TikZ flowchart: Nested box titles
I'm trying to make a flowchart with parts with nested boxes. What I'm struggling with is getting the titles inside the larger boxes. I'd like to have them in top left corner in the big boxes, but now they are above the box border.
In addition, I'm new to TikZ and any suggestions making the overall flowchart better are appreciated :)

This is what I have tried
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, fit, positioning}

% Styles
\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm]
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw, thick, inner sep=6pt, label={[font=\bfseries]north:#1}]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm] % Reduced distances for better fit

% Text1
\node (text1) [box] {text1};

% Larger box: title1
\node (text2) [box, below left=4.5cm and 4.5cm of text1, xshift=-1cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text2};
\node (text3) [box, below left=2cm and 3.3cm of text1, minimum height=1.5cm] {text3};
\node (text4) [box, below=1cm of text3, minimum height=1.5cm] {text4};
\node (text5) [box, right=0.2cm of text3, minimum height=1.5cm] {text5};
\node (text6) [box, below=1cm of text4, minimum height=1.5cm] {text6};
\node (text7) [box, below=1cm of text6, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text7};
\node (text8) [box, below left=4.5cm and 0cm of text1, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text8};
\node (text9) [box, below=1cm of text8, minimum height=1.5cm] {text9};
\node (text10) [box, right=0.3cm of text8, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text10};
\node (text11) [box, below=1cm of text10, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text11};

\node[fit=(text2) (text3) (text4) (text5) (text6) (text7) (text8) (text9) (text10) (text11), bigbox={title1}] (title1box) {};

% Larger box: title2
\node (text12) [box, below=2cm of text1, xshift=3.2cm, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text12};
\node (text13) [box, below=1cm of text12, minimum height=1.5cm] {text13};
\node (text14) [box, below=1cm of text13, minimum height=1.5cm] {text14};
\node (text15) [box, below=1cm of text14, minimum height=1.5cm] {text15};

\node[fit=(text12) (text13) (text14) (text15), bigbox={title2}] (title2box) {};

% Larger box: title3
\node (text16) [box, below=2cm of text1, xshift=6cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text16};

\node[fit=(text16), bigbox={title3}] (title3box) {};

% Larger box: title4
\node (text17) [box, below=13cm of text1, xshift=0cm] {text17};
\node (text18) [box, below=1cm of text17] {text18};

\node[fit=(text17) (text18), bigbox={title4}] (title4box) {};

% Draw arrows
\draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title1box.north);
\draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title2box.north);
\draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title3box.north);
\draw [arrow] (text3) -- (text2);
\draw [arrow] (text2) |- (text7);
\draw [arrow] (text3) -- (text4);
\draw [arrow] (text4) -- (text6);
\draw [arrow] (text6) -- (text7);
\draw [arrow] (text5) -- (text8);
\draw [arrow] (text5) ++(-0.5,-0.75) |- (text6);
\draw [arrow] (text8) -- (text9);
\draw [arrow] (text8) -- (text10);
\draw [arrow] (text9) -- (text7);
\draw [arrow] (text10) -- (text11);
\draw [arrow] (text11) |- (text7);
\draw [arrow] (text12) -- (text13);
\draw [arrow] (text13) -- (text14);
\draw [arrow] (text14) -- (text15);
\draw [arrow] (title2box) |- (title4box);
\draw [arrow] (title1box) |- (title4box);
\draw [arrow] (title3box) |- (title4box);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




Your code is really good. You are already using styles and fit. However, you should not use the deprecated \tikzstyle in new code. Instead, use \tikzset.
I would place a couple of extra coordinates so you can capture a point a bit above the smaller boxes when constructing the larger ones. Then you can just tweak the anchors to place the titles.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, fit, positioning}

% Styles
\tikzset{box/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm},
  bigbox/.style = {draw, thick, inner sep=6pt, label={[font=\bfseries,anchor=north west]north west:#1}},
  arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm] % Reduced distances for better fit

  % Text1
  \node (text1) [box] {text1};

  % Larger box: title1
  \node (text2) [box, below left=4.5cm and 4.5cm of text1, xshift=-1cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text2};
  \node (text3) [box, below left=2cm and 3.3cm of text1, minimum height=1.5cm] {text3};
  \node (text4) [box, below=1cm of text3, minimum height=1.5cm] {text4};
  \node (text5) [box, right=0.2cm of text3, minimum height=1.5cm] {text5};
  \node (text6) [box, below=1cm of text4, minimum height=1.5cm] {text6};
  \node (text7) [box, below=1cm of text6, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text7};
  \node (text8) [box, below left=4.5cm and 0cm of text1, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text8};
  \node (text9) [box, below=1cm of text8, minimum height=1.5cm] {text9};
  \node (text10) [box, right=0.3cm of text8, text width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text10};
  \node (text11) [box, below=1cm of text10, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text11};

  \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=10pt]text3.north) ;
  \node[fit=(text2) (text3) (text4) (text5) (c) (text6) (text7) (text8) (text9) (text10) (text11), bigbox={title1}] (title1box) {};

  % Larger box: title2
  \node (text12) [box, below=2cm of text1, xshift=3.2cm, text width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text12};
  \node (text13) [box, below=1cm of text12, minimum height=1.5cm] {text13};
  \node (text14) [box, below=1cm of text13, minimum height=1.5cm] {text14};
  \node (text15) [box, below=1cm of text14, minimum height=1.5cm] {text15};

  \node[fit=(text12) (text13) (text13 |- c) (text14) (text15), bigbox={title2}] (title2box) {};

  % Larger box: title3
  \node (text16) [box, below=2cm of text1, xshift=6cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {text16};

  \node[fit=(text16) (text16 |- c), bigbox={title3}] (title3box) {};

  % Larger box: title4
  \node (text17) [box, below=13cm of text1, xshift=0cm] {text17};
  \node (text18) [box, below=1cm of text17] {text18};

  \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=10pt]text17.north);
  \node[fit=(text17) (text18) (text18 |- c), bigbox={title4}] (title4box) {};

  % Draw arrows
  \draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title1box.north);
  \draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title2box.north);
  \draw [arrow] (text1) -- (title3box.north);
  \draw [arrow] (text3) -- (text2);
  \draw [arrow] (text2) |- (text7);
  \draw [arrow] (text3) -- (text4);
  \draw [arrow] (text4) -- (text6);
  \draw [arrow] (text6) -- (text7);
  \draw [arrow] (text5) -- (text8);
  \draw [arrow] (text5) ++(-0.5,-0.75) |- (text6);
  \draw [arrow] (text8) -- (text9);
  \draw [arrow] (text8) -- (text10);
  \draw [arrow] (text9) -- (text7);
  \draw [arrow] (text10) -- (text11);
  \draw [arrow] (text11) |- (text7);
  \draw [arrow] (text12) -- (text13);
  \draw [arrow] (text13) -- (text14);
  \draw [arrow] (text14) -- (text15);
  \draw [arrow] (title2box) |- (title4box);
  \draw [arrow] (title1box) |- (title4box);
  \draw [arrow] (title3box) |- (title4box);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Further suggestions:

replace the deprecated arrows library with arrows.meta and use the updated arrow tips, which are more flexible;
use chains and/or a \matrix to place the nodes (chains probably better here);
or use anchors more flexibly for placement e.g. below=1cm of <node>.south west, anchor=north west;
use scope to apply styles to all nodes within a group e.g. \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}] ... <nodes> ... \end{scope}.


Thank you very much for your thorough answer and helpful suggestions! :)
